# R get strings between specific pattern

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a long string in R with a series of values that have this pattern:

```
list <- '{s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever" and {s:K_02.01, y:02}="whatever" and {s:K_03.01, y:03}="whatever" and {s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever2" and {s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever3"'
```

I would like to extract and store in a data frame one column with all the strings that start with **{s:K_01.01** and end with **"**, and disregard all the other strings.

#### Expected output:

```
{s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever"
{s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever2"
{s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever3"
```

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all the matching using a pattern

```
{s:K_01\.01[^{}]*}="[^"]+"
```

- `{s:K_01\.01` Match a string that starts with `{s:K_01.01`
- `[^{}]*}=` Match any char except `{` or `}` and match `}=`
- `"[^"]+"` Match from `"` till `"`

[See a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gat1m3/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/fr1xnR)

```
library(stringr)

list <- '{s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever" and {s:K_02.01, y:02}="whatever" and {s:K_03.01, y:03}="whatever" and {s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever2" and {s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever3"'
str_extract_all(list, "\\{s:K_01\\.01[^\\{}]*\\}=\"[^\"]+\"")
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "{s:K_01.01, y:01}=\"whatever\""  "{s:K_01.01, y:01}=\"whatever2\""
[3] "{s:K_01.01, y:01}=\"whatever3\""
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach:

```
list <- '{s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever" and {s:K_02.01, y:02}="whatever" and {s:K_03.01, y:03}="whatever" and {s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever2" and {s:K_01.01, y:01}="whatever3"'
regmatches(list, gregexpr("\\{s:K_01\\.01.*?\\}=\".*?\"", list))[[1]]

[1] "{s:K_01.01, y:01}=\"whatever\""  "{s:K_01.01, y:01}=\"whatever2\""
[3] "{s:K_01.01, y:01}=\"whatever3\""
```

Comment: Thanks! But this captures all. While I am interested in only those starting with **{s:K_01.01** (I need to exclude those starting with **{s:K_02.01** or **{s:K_03.01** for example)

Comment: Reload your page.